# Is my geometric interpretation of $T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P = \left(\frac{\delta Q}{dT}\right)_P$ correct?

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-geometry, temperature, entropy, differentiation

I originally started writing this as just a question, but in the process of writing it I may have solved it myself. Still, I would very much appreciate if someone more knowledgeable than myself took a look at my argument, to see if it holds water.

Below you can read my original statement, and at the end you have my attempt at a solution. Is it correct? Can you provide further insights?

### TLDR

How do we correctly motivate equalities like the following?
$$T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P = \left(\frac{\delta Q}{dT}\right)_P \tag{1}$$
I do not know the formalism of differential forms, so if you give an answer in terms of that formalism, please try to also relate it back to the frameworks of more basic multivariable and vector calculus.

### Vantage point

I am reading H. B. Callen's thermodynamics textbook, and so far I have been having a great time. His careful axiomatic approach fits me very well, and I finally feel like I am starting to find my way in classical thermodynamics, which I have previously had trouble with. However, at the end of chapter three an expression like (1) appears in the definition of heat capacity, and it is giving me paus.

While I do not know the language of differential forms, I have a pretty solid understanding of differentials and vector calculus. To me, differentials are just a way of expressing linearization, or tangent spaces, if you will. That is, an expression like
$$dz = f(x,y) dx + g(x,y) dy \tag{2}$$
simply expresses that if we take a step $dx$ in the $x$-direction and a step $dy$ in the $y$-direction *on the tangent plane* of $z = z(x,y)$ at $(x,y,z)$, then the corresponding step $dz$ is given by (2). The great thing about this interpretation is that it doesn't require $dx$, $dy$, $dz$ to be "infinitesimal", or even small. Also, manipulations such as multiplying or dividing by a differential, that might otherwise seem mysterious, become perfectly reasonable when $dx$ and $dy$ are just variables like any other. And, of course, because $dz$ is a linear function of $dx$ and $dy$, the *quotients* $(dz/dx)_y$ and $(dz/dy)_x$ coincide with the partial *derivatives* $\partial z/\partial x$ and $\partial z/\partial y$. The only caveat is that we must assume that the conditions of the *implicit function theorem* are fulfilled at the point $(x,y,z)$.

From the perspective of vector calculus I might instead view (2) as primarily a prescription of the derivatives of $z=z(x,y)$. That is, (2) can be taken to, quite literally, mean
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = f, \quad \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = g.\tag{3}$$
This makes it immediately clear what we mean by an "exact differential": $dz$ is exact iff the vector field $\vec F = (f,g)$ is conservative, with potential $z(x,y)$. If $\vec F$ is *not* conservative, then (3) makes no sense, and we write $\delta z$ instead of $dz$.

### Attempt

The above framework has been powerful enough to help me make sense of all manipulations of exact differentials that I have encountered so far, but it is less clear how to use it in (1). There are two main difficulties:

1. The appearance of an inexact differential $\delta Q$ in the RHS.
2. The relation being written in terms of intensive variables $T$ and $P$ instead of extensive variables.

Point 2 is less of a difficulty, so let us start there. We first note that, in the relevant section of Callen's book, (1) is stated for a system with constant mole numbers. Hence the fundamental equation of the system, in entropy representation, has the form
$$S = S(U,V).\tag{4}$$
However, since (1) is expressed in terms of intensive variables, we wish to reexpress $S$ as a function of $T$ and $P$. We achieve this by eliminating $U$ and $V$ in favor of $T$ and $P$ with the help of the (entropy representation) equations of state
$$\left(\frac{1}{T}\right)(U,V) = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_V, \quad \left(\frac{P}{T}\right)(U,V) = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_U,\tag{5}$$
thus letting us write an expression for $S$ in the form
$$S = S(T,P).\tag{6}$$
Going on to attack point 1, we note that while $\delta Q$ is not an exact differential, $\delta Q/T = dS$ is:
$$\frac{\delta Q}{T} = dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P dT + \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)_T dP.\tag{7}$$
For a given pair $(T,P)$, (7) defines a tangent plane to the surface $S = S(T,P)$ in a cartesian $TPS$-space. Taking a step $dT$ in the $T$-direction *on this plane*, the resulting change $\delta Q/T = dS$ in $S$ becomes
$$\frac{\delta Q}{T} = dS = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P dT.\tag{8}$$
Here, the quantities $T$, $(\partial S/\partial T)_P$, and $dT$ are just numbers. Hence $\delta Q$ is also just a number, so we can rearrange and write
$$\frac{\delta Q}{dT} = T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P,\tag{9}$$
and since we took this step orthogonally to the $P$ axis, we may even write
$$\left(\frac{\delta Q}{dT}\right)_P = T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_P.\tag{10}$$

Comment: I suppose the step where we eliminate $U$ and $V$ in (5) also requires that $S$ is a convex (or concave) function of $U$ and $V$. At least locally.

Comment: I'm cautiously of the opinion that this is completely correct!